# AS3 - Events are no longer received after adding a preloader swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, preloader

This was my initial structure:
main.swf -> child.swf

Main loads various child swfs. I am dispatching events from the child swfs, and main is listening for the events. Everything was working great.

Then, I added a preloader swf, so now the structure is: 
loader.swf -> main.swf -> child.swf

I did not change the relationship between main and child at all, but now events dispatched by the child are no longer received by main. I know they are getting dispatched (using Console.log). Bubbling is set to true. Why would main no longer receive events from a child just because I wrapped everything with a loader?

EDIT:
I tried changing useWeakReference to false, in case the listener was getting garbage collected:

```
this.addEventListener(MyEvent.HELP_ME, imDesperate, false, 0, false);
```

That didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others visiting this question, the answer is to do with the ApplicationDomain (overview [here](http://code.google.com/p/maashaack/wiki/ApplicationDomain)) and was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415722/as3-events-type-coercion-failed/1415936#1415936).